# Making alarmManager able to wakeup the phone

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, alarmmanager, sleep, wakeup

I've adapted the code in http://code4reference.com/2012/07/tutorial-on-android-alarmmanager/ taking a picture every 30 sec. It works ok but when the phone goes in sleep mode it seems that the alarmManager does not make its job properly. Is there a way to make alarmManager able to wakeup the phone?

Answer (score 1):

You need to implement a WakeLock.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/PowerManager.WakeLock.html

This requires a specific permission, and is generally frowned upon by users.

Comment: The code I am using already uses PowerManager.WakeLock as you can see at the begin of the code shown in http://code4reference.com/2012/07/tutorial-on-android-alarmmanager/